# cosine in rotation computation

Tags: trigonometry, rotations

So when learning about quaternions from this video:

[YouTube lecture](https://youtu.be/MkNfQtINEjo?t=49m50s)

there is computation of cos of 110 degress angle, but I am not able to figure out what kind of theorem lead to given in video and screenshot below equation for cos or sin. I would grately appreciate any help. I can get h2 different way based on circle and right angles but cannot make it up with this 110 deg.

[cos mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsZar.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He is using the tangens half-angle formula, also called [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution)